# href isn't redirecting to link in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code (you need to open up full page to see the top of the card):

```html
       
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    
    //put the url of the girl into the quotes of imgUrl
    var imgUrl = "https://i.mdel.net/oftheminute/images/2019/07/Jill-06.jpg"
    
    //put the name of the model into the quotes of modelName
    var modelName = "My Model"
    
    //put the link to their instagram into the quotes of instagram
    var instagram = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram"
    //put the link to their twitter into the quotes of twitter
    var twitter = "https://twitter.com/twitter"
    
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = modelName;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = imgUrl;
    document.getElementById("instagram").href = instagram;
    document.getElementById("twitter").href = instagram;
    }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div class="image-area">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="" id="myImg" alt="">
            <h2 id="myText"></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
*
{
    background: #f1f2f6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.image-area
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}

.img-wrapper
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 180%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    z-index: 1;
    transform: skew(45deg);
    transition: .5s;
}

.img-wrapper:hover:before
{
    left: -180%;
}

.img-wrapper img
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 2s;
}
.img-wrapper:hover img
{
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.img-wrapper h2
{
    background: tomato;
    font-family: Poppins;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: 1s;
}

.img-wrapper:hover h2
{
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.img-wrapper ul
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.img-wrapper ul li
{
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(90deg);
    transition: .5s;
    transform-origin: left;
}

.img-wrapper:hover ul li
{
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.img-wrapper:hover ul li:nth-child(1)
{
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.img-wrapper:hover ul li:nth-child(2)
{
    transition-delay: .6s;
}

.img-wrapper:hover ul li:nth-child(3)
{
    transition-delay: .8s;
}

.img-wrapper:hover ul li:nth-child(4)
{
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.img-wrapper ul li a
{
    color: tomato;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.img-wrapper ul li i
{
    color: tomato;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.img-wrapper ul li i:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
</style>
```

the only problem with this is, when you try to click the `instagram` or `twitter` logo, it doesn't redirect to ig or twitter at all, and I dont know why! How do I fix this? I basically put the variable `instagram` into the `id` of the `<a>` tag, but leave the href empty. That is because I thought the variable in the id would act as the href based on my variable and how I am writing to the html. I am probably wrong tho!

Comment: _"you need to open up full page to see the top of the card"_ - Then this is not a [mcve] (with the focus on _minimal_)

Comment: @Andreas the card is to big for the snippet size, thats why you need to open the the code snippet full page ......

Comment: Yes, that's why this is not a [mcve]. You're supposed to debug the problem. And the first step is to remove anything that is not relevant for the problem. Like unnecessary CSS, or overly big images, or unnecessary code, ...

Comment: The `<style>` has to be a child of the `<head>`

Comment: @Andreas what dou you mean?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (if we ignore the "error" because of the frame policy from instagram/twitter): https://jsfiddle.net/boLtcjph/

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the javascript console logs you can see the error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.instagram.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

This means instagram and twitter set a header that forbids you to display the pages on a frame. You'll need to do a full page redirect instead.

UPDATE:

The frame thing was just inside SO. Outside SO the links worked for me. Either way I suggest you don't use javascript for that at all. Just se the `href` directly on html and you'll have an easier time. e.g.

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/instagram" target="_blank">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: oh okay, that is interesting! How do I do a full page redirect? My original thought is it would still be with the href?

Comment: I recommend just setting `href` and probably adding `target="_blank"` so it opens up in a new tab (which is a good user experience when leaving your page). No javascript should even be necessary for that.

Comment: The frame is from SO (the snippet)

Comment: ah, you're right. Outside of SO it just worked. I did notice you set both to instagram though, so the twitter one dosn't work.